# In Postgres, duplicate rows on a column are not detected by select group by, but unique index built is failing with duplicate values

Tags: postgresql, group-by, collation

I have a table with `users` and column `username`. I am trying to build an index on the `users#username` column but it is failing with an error for a duplicate value. The value detected is an Arabic character set value. Note that when I do

```
select count(*), username from users group by username having count(*)>=2;
```

it returns `0`.

The collation of the database is `en_us.UTF8`.

Why does the `group by` fail to detect the duplicates whereas the unique index built finds them and fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it uses a corrupted index.

Try

```
SET enable_indexscan = off;
SET enable_bitmapscan = off;

SELECT count(*),
       username
FROM users
GROUP BY username HAVING count(*)>=2;
```

That way, you force PostgreSQL to use a sequential scan rather than the unreliable data from a corrupted index.